# WYSIHTML5 character counter for IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, wysihtml5

I have implemented a character counter for the wysihtml5 editor in my site but it does not work in IE8.  I get an error on the following line of code which I use to get the current character count from the WYSIWYG editor.

```
return document.getElementsByClassName('wysihtml5-sandbox')[0].contentWindow.document.body.innerText.length;
```

This works in FF and Chrome, but IE8 shows the following error:

[image]

Is there any way to get this to work in IE8?

Comment: getElementByClassName is not supported by IE8 : http://caniuse.com/#search=getElementsByClassName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.wysihtml5-sandbox')[0].contentWindow.document.body.innerText.length;
```

I tried this and it works.  I feel stupid now.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own, since getElementByClassName isn't supported in IE8.

Edit: Much simpler way is to use

```
document.querySelectorAll('.classname')
```

So you want:

```
return document.querySelectorAll('.wysihtml5-sandbox')[0].contentWindow.document.body.innerText.length;
```

Does that work?

Answer (score 0):

I've used this code.

This line must be after you create the WYSIHTML5 object:

```
$('.wysihtml5-sandbox').contents().find('body').on("keyup",countChars);
```

The function "countChars" definition is:

```
function countChars() {
    var text = $('.wysihtml5-sandbox').contents().find('body').html().replace('&nbsp;',' '); //Remove space tags
    var limit = 50; //Max text lenght

    if(text.length > limit) {
       //Your action when it's invalid
    } else {
       //Your action when it's valid
    }

    //In my case this is a span where the number is show
    var remains = limit - text.length;
    $('#char-counter').html(String(remains)); 
}
```

I hope it could help you!